# Why the quickstart code in Google Speech API does not require our API Access Key?

Tags: speech-recognition

Thank you anyone of your time in looking/answering the qns.
I realize that the quick-start code provided by Google is able to use immediately for speech recognition in that case why do Google still want us to create the API key and how does Google charge us?

Below is the code

```
// [START speech_quickstart]

using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;
using System;

namespace GoogleCloudSamples
{
    public class QuickStart
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
            var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en",
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile("audio.raw"));
            foreach (var result in response.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
// [END speech_quickstart]
```

Note: I do not own any rights in the above code, Google cater the codes available to the public.

Comment: Interesting. Previously the API would throw an error if the request wasn't authenticated. My guess is that this is a bug that Google will probably fix soon.

Comment: I asked the person who posted the tutorial, he mention that it was authenticated when I installed the sdk on my laptop. But it makes no sense, if I will to bring the program to another laptop, doesn't it cant work anymore?